# A simple limit question

Tags: calculus, limits

If I set $f(x):=x+1$ for $x < 4$, is it true that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $10$ does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is not defined near $10$, then we certainly can't talk about that limit. In general, we can only hope to talk about $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ if $a$ is a [limit point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of the domain of $f$.

Comment: Thanks! So can I state that this limit does not exist? Or is there another way to express the fact that this limit can't be computed?

Comment: Saying that it does not exist is fine.

Comment: Thanks!! So when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist (that's how we laymen describe it), is it always true that $a$ is not a limit point of the domain of $f$?

Comment: You can, for instance, define a function from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to some interval containing -1 and 1, such that f maps the positive numbers to 1 and the negative numbers to -1. Zero most certainly is a limit point of the domain, yet you can't define said limit to the point 0. I guess that answers your question.

(Note that you can define both the limit $\downarrow 0$ and $\uparrow 0$.)

Comment: @guestdumb: Not necessarily. Even when $a$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ need not exist, as HSN's example so aptly shows.